# Java Web Application connect to MYSQL and SQL SERVER

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, spring

I have a SpringMvc Web App running perfectly on a tomcat server alongside MySql.
What i need to do is that i need to store some data to another database on a SQL Server in another hosting.

So i am wondering if a spring mvc project has the capability to have simultaneously an MySql connection and SQL Server connection.
If not what could you advice me since i need to copy the contents of the mysql to sql every once in a while (say for instance in an interval of 2h).

Thanks

Comment: you have to create 2 connection one for SQL SERVER and another one for MYSQL and use those connection object based on your requirement

Comment: Ohh i see... Thanks i will try it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two different DataSources with respective Drivers and Connection Credentials. It should work fine.